# html5 баннер Google Adwords

Tags: html5, google-adwords

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, сделали html5 баннер, в котором есть взаимодействие с пользователем, надо пару раз кликнуть по нему, чтобы менялся контент. Загружают этот баннер в Google Adwords. Суть в том, что при клике на баннер, перебрасывает сразу на указанный сайт. 
Вопрос: как этого избежать, чтоб прежде чем юзера кидало на сайт магазина, он мог взаимодействовать с баннером через клик? Спасибо.

Лайтбоксы делают не то, что нам нужно. Они вызывают модальное окно с подобием слайдера. Нам не нужно увеличивать баннер. Есть такая прекрасная реклама world of tanks, http://cdn2.worldoftanks.com/d_parhimovich/fbatwork/banners/wot/refuel/ там идёт клик, после чего какое-то действие, а потом, при втором клике уже идет переадресация.

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос. Не надо править ответ добавляя в него информацию не являющуюся ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не поверите, но в справочном центре AdWords есть ответ на ваш вопрос.

Вам необходимо создать лайтбокс. Вот [инструкция](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6145130).

Пользоваться справкой иногда бывает полезно.